# Why won't FreeRadius allow WPA2 Enterprise/PEAP Wi-Fi connections?

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt, ubuntu-13.04, freeradius

First a bit of background: I've been tinkering with this on and off for a few days and it's getting frustrating. I've got a NetGear r6300 loaded up with DD-WRT v24/SP2 Giga and I've configured SSH to log into the console.

I'm trying (and failing) to set up WPA2 Enterprise Wi-Fi for which I'm using the built in version of FreeRadius. I've got Ubuntu 13.04 on my local computer.

- I've configured FreeRadius, the Radius and Wireless Security information via the GUI on the router.
- I've successfully tested user authentication with radtest from the SSH console
- I've downloaded the ca.pem certificate from the /etc/freeradius/certs folder
- I've downloaded the TestUser-cert.P12, TestUser-cert.pem, TestUser-key.pem, TestUser-req.pem certificates from the /etc/freeradius/certs/clients folder

Here are my router settings:

**Services/FreeRadius**

Server Certificate:

- Country Code: CA
- State or Province: Ontario
- Locality: Toronto
- Organization / Company: Test Company
- Email Address: info@testcompany.com
- Common Certificate Name: Test Radius Certificate
- Expires: 365 days
- Passphrase: TestCertificatePassphrase

Settings

- Radius Port: 1812

Clients:

- 127.0.0.1     TestRadiusSharedSecret
- 192.168.1.0   TestRadiusSharedSecret

Users:

- User 1

  - Username: TestUser1
  - Password: TestPassword
  - Downspeed: 9999999
  - Upseed: 9999999
  - Expires (Days): 365
  - Enabled: Checked

**Wireless/Wireless Security**

- Security Mode: WPA2 Enterprise
- WPA Algorithms: TKIP+AES
- Radius Server Address: 127.0.0.1
- Radius Auth Port: 1812
- Radius Shared Secret: TestRadiusSharedSecret
- Key Renewal: 3600

**Wireless/Radius**

- MAC Radius Client: Enable
- MAC Format: aabbccddeeff
- Radius Auth Server Address: 127.0.0.1
- Radius Auth Server Port: 1812
- Maximum Unauthenticated Users: 0
- Password Format: Shared Key
- Radius Auth Shared Secret: TestRadiusSharedSecret

From the SSH console I get the following output from RadTest:

```
$radtest TestUser1 TestPassword 127.0.0.1 0 TestRadiusSharedSecret

Sending Access-Request of id 231 to 127.0.0.1 port 1812
    User-Name = "TestUser1"
    User-Password = "TestPassword"
    NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.1.1
    NAS-Port = 0
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
rad_recv: Access-Accept packet from host 127.0.0.1 port 1812, id=231, length=68
    WISPr-Bandwidth-Max-Down = 1650064384
    RP-Downstream-Speed-Limit = 9999999
    WISPr-Bandwidth-Max-Up = 1650064384
    RP-Upstream-Speed-Limit = 9999999
```

When I run `radiusd -d /jffs/etc/freeradius -X` from the console and attempt to connect my machine to the Wi-Fi with the following settings:

[image: Screenshot of Wi-Fi Settings]

the connection fails...

From the exerpt from the log, I glean that it's something relating to the SharedSecret between my Radius client and FreeRadius, but I can't figure out what or why because the shared secret is the same in the Radius client and the FreeRadius configurations...

```
rad_recv: Access-Request packet from host 127.0.0.1 port 37619, id=6, length=80
        User-Name = "c48508cf0a6c"
        NAS-Port = 1
        NAS-Port-Type = Wireless-802.11
        User-Password = "TestRadiusSharedSecret"
# Executing section authorize from file /jffs/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
+- entering group authorize {...}
++[mschap] returns noop
[eap] No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
++[eap] returns noop
++[files] returns noop
[pap] WARNING! No "known good" password found for the user.  Authentication may fail because of this.
++[pap] returns noop
ERROR: No authenticate method (Auth-Type) found for the request: Rejecting the user
Failed to authenticate the user.
Login incorrect: [c48508cf0a6c/TestRadiusSharedSecret] (from client DD-WRT-RADIUS port 1)
Using Post-Auth-Type REJECT
  WARNING: Unknown value specified for Post-Auth-Type.  Cannot perform requested action.
Delaying reject of request 3 for 1 seconds
Going to the next request
```

Here is the [full Radius log for the wi-fi connection attempt](http://pastebin.com/zvKDPZn4)

It seems like I'm missing something, but I'm unsure what that could be. Can anyone see what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

You missing your EAP module configuration. I assume this is freeradius 3? Either way, look at your log. The EAP modules noops. That means there is nothing to do. If you're using PEAP, you have to have the eap module with the password to for your certificate.